# defined column aliase name in query how to use in where clause with in same query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email,
(case 
       when user.AT_ST ='A' then 'Act'
       when user.AT_ET = 'E' then 'Est'
       end ) as Act_Est 
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN locations
ON users.id = locations.user_id
WHERE Act_Est  IN (' ')
```

Here this alias name want to use with in same query not creating with other sub queries .
Because if I use other select sub query it fetching first inner sub query and retrieving all the data first and then applying where condition .

So need some help on this .

Comment: On suggestion: Use `ELSE` in the `CASE` statement, if you are going to deal only with `'A'` and `'E'` then filter in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx#Anchor_2): "... because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses". WHERE is step 4.

Answer (score 2):

Use **With Statement**:

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT 
        users.first_name, 
        users.last_name, 
        users.email, 
        (case when user.AT_ST ='A' then 'Act' when user.AT_ET = 'E' then 'Est' end ) as Act_Est 
    FROM users 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN locations ON users.id = locations.user_id
) 
SELECT
    *
FROM T
WHERE T.Act_Est IN (' ')
```

With Statement is a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement

Answer (score 2):

You can use one more `SELECT` as the below:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
(   
    SELECT 
        users.first_name, 
        users.last_name, 
        users.email,
        (case 
               when user.AT_ST ='A' then 'Act'
               when user.AT_ET = 'E' then 'Est'
               end ) as Act_Est 
    FROM 
        users LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        locations ON users.id = locations.user_id   
) A
WHERE 
    A.Act_Est  IN (' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

To have intermediate variables for futher calculations use CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email, vars.Act_Est 
FROM users 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT case 
       when users.AT_ST ='A' then 'Act'
       when users.AT_ET = 'E' then 'Est'
       end as Act_Est) vars
LEFT OUTER JOIN locations
ON users.id = locations.user_id
WHERE vars.Act_Est  IN (' ')
```

Comment: Actually all the above options is taking more time to fetch the result .

Comment: @bvpk1234 Can you share your timing comparison? My experience is inline CROSS APPLY as above has almost no impact on perfomance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all the above options are taking more time .

My actual query is like below .

```
   When (  T.co  in ('ps', 'pi', 'ri')) then ('PFG') 
   When ( T.co  in ('qs', 'qb')) then ('QBE')
   When ( T.co  in ('sr')) then ('OTH')
   When ( T.co  in ('rg', 'qi')) then ('EX2')
   When ( T.co  in ('LT', 'SL', 'ST')) then ('EX3')
   End ) as Company_Group ,
```

Here I want to use in where clause Company group directly .IF I use any with clause or putting this in sub query  it is executing the above query entirely and executing where clause .so it taking lot of time So my requirment how I can directly pass my where condition for aliase columns in this query .

Comment: Cross apply after case statment ,I am getting incorrect syntax near case I am getting  @Serg

Comment: Hi Serg is this Cross Apply will work  while creating  procedure,Because it is not working for me when trying to use this to create procedure .But actual SQL it is properly working and giving exact result within time .Thanks for your help..:)